# "Who's been here" vs "Who was here"

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-constructions

"Who's been here?"

"Who was here"

What's the difference between these sentences and when should I use them? And what "i've been here" means by itself?

Comment: Present Perfect (the first version) implies something in the past that's very relevant to current time of speaking (speaker comes home from work early and is concerned that he can smell cigarettes, but neither he nor his wife smoke). You wouldn't normally ask *Who's been here ten years ago?*, for example, but there's nothing syntactically unusual about using Simple Past to ask *Who was here before you were born?*

Answer (score 1):

“I was here,” is usually used to say that at one point of time in particular, your location was here.

“I’ve been here,” or, “I have been here,” is used to say that at any point in time prior to now, your location was here.

For example, if your coworker asks if you were in the office last week, an appropriate response would be, “I was here.”

By contrast, if someone asks if this is your first time visiting New York, an appropriate response would be, “No, I’ve been here,” to say that it was not your first time.

——

For the question version, while they can be used with similar distinctions to the non-question version, “Who’s been here?,” can also be used with the same meaning as, “Who was here?,” but with a negative tone implying the person should not have been there or that you disapprove of their having been there.

For example, if your housemate says they had some friends over while you were at work, you might ask, “Who was here?”

If you come home to find your spouse sitting down two half-full drinks on the table, and they’re dodging your questions, you might ask, “Who’s been here?,” although, “Who was here?,” would also work but with a softer tone to it.

You might also ask, “Who’s been here?,” if you’re visiting somewhere with a group of people to ask which of them have been here prior to now.